# How to catch null or undefined query string parameters in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, query-string

Grabbing query string values is easy in SharePoint with some javascript...

```
var xid = GetUrlKeyValue("ItemId", false, location.href);
```

But what if ItemId didn't exist in certain instances, how can you code in some logic to first determine the query string item exists, and branch accordingly? I've tried a few approaches, but not having any luck.

```
if ((typeof xid!== "undefined") && (xid!== null)) {
        alert(xid);
    } else {
        alert("undefined");}
```

and

```
if (typeof xid === "undefined") {
        alert("undefined");
    } else {
        alert("defined");}
```

Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 1):

`GetUrlKeyValue` function in SharePoint is defined in `init.js`.

If the key is not found in the specified URL then it returns an empty string("").

So, you can check it simply like below:

```
if(xid) {
    alert("Found.");
} else {
    alert("Not Found").
}
```

Or

```
if(xid == "") {
    alert("Found.");
} else {
    alert("Not Found").
}
```

Comment: Does this answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code :

```
if ((typeof xid!== undefined) && (xid!== null)) {
    alert(xid);
} else {
    alert("undefined");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough couldn't get these working. Ended up just using if(xid == "")